# Setting multiple variables of an object at the same time

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to set multiple variables of an object at the same time. For example I have the following code:

```
_p.a=1; 
_p.b=2;
_p.c=3;
```

What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
_p.[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}];  // this code does not do the trick
```

Is there a way to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an object _p and want to exted it using another object - in your case, a literal.

jquery has a utility for that:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
 $.extend(_p, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3});
```

so does underscore:

http://underscorejs.org/#extend

```
_.extend(_p,  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

```
var _p = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
Object.defineProperties(_p, {
  'a': {
    value: 1,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
  },
  'b': {
    value: 2,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
  },
  'c': {
    value: 3,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true
  }
});
console.log(_p); //Object {foo: "bar", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: I think that even thought this is correct, OP's original code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use something like this:

```
Object.prototype.setProps = function(props){
    for(var i in props){
        if(props.hasOwnProperty(i))
            this[i] = props[i];
    }
}
```

With:

```
_p.setProps({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
```